# Gtk# TreeView set a single cell to have a different renderer?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#, gtktreeview

OK this is probably insane, but I want to be able to have a check box at the very top of every row in my tree view. This box will "disable" or "enable" the ability to use the column. Oh I think it should be mentioned that I'm using a ListStore and am using C#, mono, GTK#. However, ill take anything and try to figure it out.

I'll even accept a way to make two views where the columns line up.

So, possible? or just insane?

Comment: You only want checkboxes or you want checkboxex and textbox in the same cell?, you will use it like a header?

Comment: the first row i want only a checkbox in the cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's an old post, but the answer might help someone else.

It's possible and quite simple to be honest. You have to add your custom widget (for instance a `Gtk.ToggleButton` or your own implementation of a checkbox) to the `Gtk.TreeViewColumn.Widget` property.

Job done! :)

You might find also quite useful a `Gtk.TreeViewColumn.Clicked` event to subscribe to.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Excellent solution, that not many people know about -- I didn't!

Comment: Came back and found this answer sweet. I will definitely use this in the future. BTW it sucks when people come later and down vote my answer without thinking about the post time. :(